# How To Generate Dynamic Target File In Informatica Based On Column Value

Tags: informatica

Scenario: Generate different flat file target based on the Location name, like separate files for Mumbai.dat, Bangalore.dat, and Delhi.dat

Source file:
Dept name Dept ID Location
DWH         1     Mumbai
Java        2     Bangalore
Dot net     3     Delhi

I am able to achieve it by transaction control component and output file target field but the problem is I am trying to create workflow and in session associated to this mapping I want to pass input file and output file as parameters that will populate through parameter file but I am getting error in reading input file however when I hard code the path with filename it's reading that perfectly.Apart from this output file is getting created with zero byte and not dynamically when I am trying to pass parameters for that.Can someone please help with workflow parameter file and how to use it in this case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Generate Dynamic Target File In Informatica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53030693/how-to-generate-dynamic-target-file-in-informatica)

Answer (score 0):

Edit your target file definition and tick to include a FileName port. Then its normal mapping logic to pass the desired filename through to this port. Informatica will send the record to file with name as specified by the port