# How To Generate Dynamic Target File In Informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

Scenario: Generate different flat file target based on the Location name, like separate files for Mumbai.dat, Bangalore.dat, and Delhi.dat

Source Table:

```
Dept name   Dept ID  Location
DWH          1        Mumbai
Java         2        Bangalore
Dot net      3        Delhi
```

I am able to achieve the output through transaction control and output field file name but the problem is I am creating workflow and session for this associated with this mapping but problem is I need to pass the input and outside in session through parameter file.I created parameter file but the output is not coming as expected however when I hard code the input and output file it's coming as expected.Can someone please help me how to write the parameter file for this scenario and how to pass parameters for input and output file in this case.Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to pass through parameter? source and target directory? What are the parameter names you are using?

Comment: Hi @Samik I am trying to pass parameter through parameter file I tried $inputfile and $outputfilename.

Comment: The input file parameter name has to be  `$InputFileName_something`. And I believe output file name would not be applicable here, since you are generating output file name through transaction control.

Comment: @Samik in that case do I need to hard code the output file directory and name in session and what's the difference between passing $inputfile_something and normal $inputfile?